Holdout/Transparent shader bug?
I am using a mix shader node to transition between a holdout and a transparent shader, and therefore create a fade in/out effect. There is nothing wrong when the mix shader node is at 0 or 1, but when it's in between, a grey area is visible. What could be causing this ?


Hello, are you using Eevee, in that case what Blend Mode option have you selected in the Material > Settings?

+1 to moonboots, Also, don't take the way your effects look while scrubbing back and forth through the VSE timeline to get an idea of what the final result will look like. VSE uses a bunch of different tricks to buffer the video so it can playback smoothly, but the playback will prolly have a lower framerate/resolution and other compression artefacts. Try rendering a dozen frames or so and see if the problem persists there.

The Transparent BSDF should make something transparent... what do you need the Holdout for? By the way I see you have set the Alpha of the transparent color to 0. This is not necessary and actually has no effect in the Shader Editor.

@moonbots I tried Alpha Blend at first, when I encoutered the problem. I then switched to Alpha Hashed, which gave me the result I showed in my post.

@Jakemoyo I rendered a frame, which gave me the same result.

@GordonBrinkmann The objects I'm trying to fade in almost all have different materials, which means I'd have to go to each one to animate themm fading out. Trying to avoid the hassle, I cutoff shapes of a plane to hide the elements I need and fade them in.

Since you're mixing Transparency with Holdout,  I guess this is a duplicate question then. This question is similar to: Objects in holdout collection showing in render when their alpha value in Principled BSDF is not 1 or 0. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
